# prove that the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a square

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given $ABCD$  a quadrilateral such that $AB\parallel CD$ and $\angle ACD=45^0, \angle A=90^0, \angle D=90^0 $

Need to prove that $ABCD$ is a square.

I tried to use circles but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

thanks.

**EDIT**: i added a crucial details about angles $A$ and $D$.

Comment: Have you tried to find a counterexample to your claim?

Comment: no, why? it's not true?

Comment: It's not even almost true.

Comment: @ TonyK - why not? i was told by my teacher that it's true.he gave me a clue to use 2 circles but i can't see how it can help.

Comment: i forgot to add crucial details.. see my edit. sorry

Comment: Still not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a square. You are given that $\angle A$ and $\angle D$ are $90^\circ$, but you are not guaranteed in $BC \parallel AD$. In fact, $\angle D = 90^\circ$ is implied by $AB \parallel CD$

[image]

Comment: but $\angle ACD=45^0$ so $AD=DC$

Comment: yes. true. What about the remaining sides? Dont go by my diagram. AD = DC.

Comment: You have no information to conclude that $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$

Comment: I've never seen wronger right angles!

Comment: if we build $BD$, it won't help?  i can see that $DB=2R$ maybe i can show that $AC=2R$ as well.

Comment: @TonyK just made them *right*er

Comment: @dona what is $R$

Comment: @Tim - radius of the circle that block $ABD$.